# Google speech-to-text Getting inaccurate results with same function call

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I hope to get some help here. I built a program that uses Google Speech-to-Text to convert wav-files with spoken numbers to text. When I upload these to the google speech testing site I get correct results, yet when I use the same function call from within my own application some numbers are swallowed. So for example the spoken number 1114343 works fine on google's own site, but my script would give me 14343 for example. This erratic behaviour is not consistent (and voice quality is very good btw) and it pretty much breaks my program when we can't rely on it.

I took some time debugging and using five alternative results I sometimes get the right results so I went for using the longest. This does not work either because it will use the results with written numbers "zwei"(two) as longer than "2" of course. I also tright speechcontexts but with absolutely no difference in the results.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and found help? From the google site by checking their function json representation I'm using the exact same call with different results. Note that I'm using German language in both cases. Thanks in advance, this error is driving me crazy.

```
GoogleCredential googleCredential;
using (Stream m = new FileStream(keyPath, FileMode.Open))
    googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(m);
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
    googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());
var speech = SpeechClient.Create(channel);
var ergebnis = "";
var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
{
    Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
    EnableAutomaticPunctuation = false,
    Model = "default",
    LanguageCode = "de-DE",
    MaxAlternatives = 5,
    SpeechContexts = { new SpeechContext { Phrases = {  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20", "eins", "zwei", "drei", "vier", "fünf", "sechs", "sieben", "acht", "neun", "null","zehn","elf","zwölf","dreizehn","vierzehn","fünfzehn","sechzehn","siebzehn","achtzehn","neunzehn","zwanzig" } } }
}, RecognitionAudio.FromBytes(audioStream));
var wahrscheinlichstesErgebnis = "";

foreach(var result in response.Results)
{
    foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
    }

    if (isnumberfield)
    {

        wahrscheinlichstesErgebnis = wahrscheinlichstesErgebnis + " " + result.Alternatives.OrderByDescending(x => Regex.Replace(x.Transcript, @"\D", "").Length).First().Transcript;
    }
    else
    {
        wahrscheinlichstesErgebnis = wahrscheinlichstesErgebnis + " " + result.Alternatives.OrderByDescending(x => x.Transcript.Length).First().Transcript;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if this turned out to be a problem with the C# client library specifically. Are you able to test with (say) the Python client library? It would be good to determine whether this is a general API problem or the client library.

Comment: @jonSkeet I will see if I can test that. My best guess so far was that there might be some kind of setting in the Google Cloud Dashboard that switches between "low accuracy / free" and "high accurracy / paid" or something like that. It really does feel like there's a switch somewhere that I might be missing.

Comment: Have you tried setting RecognitionConfig.UseEnhanced=true?

Comment: Try checking what you are using for "model" and "useEnhanced" https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig